# How to add levels to Flappybird like game?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This might be bit confusing.

This is my override function ATM, where my walls are spawning every 2 seconds.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    if gameStarted == false{

        gameStarted = true

        mexican.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true


        let spawn = SKAction.run({
            () in

            self.createWalls()

        })
        let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)
        let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([delay, spawn])
        let spawnDelayForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnDelay)
        self.run(spawnDelayForever)


        let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.width + wallPair.frame.width)
        let movePipes = SKAction.moveBy(x: -distance - 50, y: 0, duration: TimeInterval( 0.01 * distance))
        let removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePipes,removePipes])

        mexican.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        mexican.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 65))
```

I have found a tutorial where the wall spawn duration is made faster but I am unsure how to incorporate this into my code as they have used a new function.

My walls are being spawned in the override function which makes it hard for me to call this when adding my if statement.

```
     func startNewLevel(){

           levelNumber += 1

           if self.actionForKey("spawningEnemies") != nil{
           self.removeActionForKey("spawningEnemies")
           }

           var levelDuration = timeInterval()
           switch levelNumber {
           case 1: levelDuration = 2.0
           case 2: levelDuration = 1.8
           case 3: levelDuration = 1.6
           default: levelDuration = 0.5
           print("Cannot find level into")
           }

           let spawn = SKAction.run(spawnEnemy)
           let waitToSpawn = SKAction.waitForDuration(levelDuration)
           let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([waitToSpawn, spawn])
           let spawnForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnSequence)
           self.runAction(spawnForever, withKey: "spawningEnemies")
```

This is where I would be calling the function startNewLevel() but my wall spawning is set up in override func touchedBegan.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.bird && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.wall{


        score += 1
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        firstBody.node?.removeFromParent()

        if score == 10 || score == 15 || score == 20{
        startNewLevel()

        if score > UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "HIGHSCORE") {
            saveHighScore()


        }

    }
    else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.bird && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.wall{

        score += 1
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()


        if score > UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "HIGHSCORE") {
            saveHighScore()

        }

    }
```

This is probably really confusing but if anyone gets me HOLA you will be my favourite person on the earth.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Is it possible to call an override func?